# Filling an SP column with SQL data

Tags: javascript, sql

As part of an internship assignment, I'm working with SharePoint 2013. I'm completely new to SharePoint in general.

Part of this assignment is a labeling system. The idea is that users can add labels to specific documents. There's two types of labels we want: Global and Personal.

Global labels are labels that anyone can add, and everyone can see.
So if Pete and John both add a label to Document A, they both see both labels.
The Managed Metadata feature in SharePoint seems to serve this purpose, to my relief. :)

Personal labels are specific to users, So if Pete and John both add a label to Document A, they only see the labels they themselves added. This is where my "problem" starts to arise.
I wasn't able to find a way to apply the Managed Metadata for this feature, so I started looking at Apps or Solutions to fix this problem.

Right now, I'm looking at making a new SQL database, or a new table in the Content database and then have an App connect to that when the list loads, taking the appropriate labels according to the user that's logged in.

However, I can't find a lot of information on connecting to the SQL DB via a SharePoint App. Sadly I can only use Javascript in these apps.
Does anyone have any experience with such a thing?
Any help would be much appreciated!

Kind regards,
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SharePoint Designer to create Business Connectivity Services (BCS / BDC) connections to SQL.  There is a great article about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819133.aspx (Article is about 2010, but applies to 2013)

Basically you end up interacting with SQL data as if it were SharePoint data.

Comment: One other note I would make:  DO NOT UNDER ANY CIRCUMSTANCES modify SharePoint's databases.  If you want to use a SQL database for this, create a new SQL database on the server so that you don't interfere with SharePoint operations.